# I would like to play audio messages on Android phone by looping speaker output back to the mic using a slitter. Would it work?

Tags: android, audio

I would like to build an auto-dialler app that connects to my house alarm. Upon an alarm the android app shall call me and play a pre-recorded message. I have no issues with the app itself but I know that I cant play an audio into the phone call (or I can play an audio file through the speaker and hope the mic picks it up). I was wondering if I loop the speaker output back to the mic if I can play the audio messages. The loop would be done using one of these:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, no it doesnt. There is though some sort of signal looping back to the phone from the microphone. I'll do some further tests and update this post again